# Playing blob's recorded by javascript MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder-api

I am developing audio chat.  Sounds are recorded in a browser (Firefox 91.02, javascript) using MediaRecorder that produces blobs of audio type - I have used MediaRecorder.start(timeslice) method in order to get chunks (blobs) of the sound every  milliseconds.  The blobs will be sent to server, which retranslate them to another clients, which will listen in their browsers.
The test version records sound and play using Audio object it in the only browser (without sending to network). Each blob that I got every  milliseconds I try to play independently.
The problem I have faced is: only the first blob was played correctly, other are not played (browser says: data format is not suitable).  I guess this occurs because of I try to play sounds blobs independently.
The question is: is there a solution  to record sound blobs which I can play independently - not joining them for player (except for stopping the mediarecorder  and restarting periodically)  ?